# SharePoint 2010 Content organizer /management

Tags: content-organizer

Can the new Content organizer feature of SharePoint 2010 copy content across web sites, site collections or sub sites?
It's activated at the web level it seems to be scoped to that level only - no ancestors, siblings or children seem to be available in the Target Location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to deal with this is to create a Content Organizer rule which has the destination set to 'Another Content Organizer in a different site' - this allows you to move content *between webs in a site collection* (from memory the dropdown is only populated with other webs in the current site collection which have the Content Organizer feature activated). In the target site's Content Organizer you would have a different rule, i.e. to actually put the item where in that web it should go.

I talk about some of this stuff in [ECM platform enhancements - Content Organizer, List Throttling, Enterprise Content Types etc](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/12/ecm-platform-enhancements-content.html), and cover some "what if" scenarios related to Content Organizer.

Comment: I can't seem to see destination field when I create the Rule? I can set the Target location but if I try to specify a different web I get an invalid target path error. If I browse I only have local libraries.

Comment: Ah it's not strictly the 'Destination' field, you need to select the radio button above and choose 'Another Content Organizer in a different site'. The image in my blog post (at http://lh5.ggpht.com/_DPonmXhJQ4g/SyF2O6-oP3I/AAAAAAAAAg0/YaRjZ1VcrgM/s1600-h/ContentOrganizerRules%5B3%5D.png - I *think* this is a reliable link on my Google-hosted blog), shows this.

Does that help?

Comment: Weird! I don't seem to have that option, see - http://www.accidentlinedirect.co.uk/images/contentorganizer.jpg
Have I forgot to turn something on?

Comment: Do you have other webs in the site collection which also have the Content Organizer feature activated?

Comment: yes, I've just created a new site and activated the feature to make sure but still no radio button option - this is odd. As a side note can you copy content to another site collection/web app?

Comment: Just taken a look at my SP2010 VM now I'm at home - I've set this up for a talk before, and from memory there are two elements to this:

- In Central Admin, you need to define a 'Send To Connection' for each other site collection whose Content Organizer you want to send things to
- In the current site, in the 'Content Organizer Settings link in Site Settings, you need to check the 'Allow rules to specify another site as a target location' checkbox.

From which you can derive you CAN send content to another site collection/web app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint about the "Send To Connection"  - helped me to find 
[the enclosed detailed post including screenshots](http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/dupont_thomas/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=30).
Why can't they make a straight forward feature to activate it all...?!